# Help on French Math Education Paper

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

I am looking for very basic (probably I should say very elementary) papers in french designed for elementary school teachers and elementary school educators. I would appreciate if someone can provide me a site or paper for that.I obviously do not want lenghty one. I need one or two pages long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les articles de la revue [Tangente, l'aventure mathématique](http://tangente.poleditions.com/) ne sont pas tous complètement élémentaires mais le lectorat français de la revue est censé être constitué de collégiens (11-14 ans) et au-delà.

Les publications du [Kangourou des mathématiques](http://www.mathkang.org/default.html), en lien avec les concours du même nom (pour les élèves français à partir des classes de CE2, 8 ans, jusqu'au baccalauréat et même un peu au delà, 17-18 ans), peuvent également vous intéresser.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you will find exactly, but maybe you could try:

$\bullet$  http://xavier.hubaut.info/coursmath/somm.htm

$\bullet$ http://numdam.org

$\bullet$ [*Francophone Mathematics Resources*](http://globegate.utm.edu/french/topics/math.html)

Regards

Comment: Gotcha!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, it is, and so do I!

Answer (score 0):

I will also add some other sources :

( add the http:// when needed, I couldn't due to a lack of reputation points )

http://www.animath.fr/spip.php?rubrique292&lang=fr ( the website in general is great, you should translate the page using google page translate)

Here is a site that gives you many sites related to elementary level maths : 
www.lasouris-web.org/primaire/math.html

Here is a website that give you  practice papers for elementary level maths : 
www.exofiches.net/elementaire-cycle2-cp-ce1.php
Go in the math section
Example : www.exofiches.net/PDF/suite-de-nombres.pdf

Elementary level translate in école primaires or élémentaire in French, if you need to look for any more papers, I can help you with your ressearch or you can just type, "école primaires maths exercices", "école primaires mathématiques leçons" and you will get lots of results.